# highcharts legend-item text to align below legend item

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am trying to place the Highcharts legend item text below the legend. i tried to display block for the legend inside highcharts function nothing works to move the text exactly below the highcharts Legend. Any help is appreciated.

```
 legend: {
            enabled: true,
            symbolWidth: 85,
            symbolHeight: 15,
            align: 'left',

            // itemStyle:{
            //  float: 'left',
            //  display: 'block',
            //  position: 'relative'
            // }
            //useHTML: true
}
```

Comment: Could you attach a mockup of that?

Comment: I did a small hack here. but i am not sure to use this as a solution. And also need help how to wrap the legend text if it is too long after placing the legend-text below the legend.    http://jsfiddle.net/bdhbL1xy/4/

Comment: Please attach an image with your concept.

Answer (score 0):

I did a small hack here. but i am not sure to use this as a solution. And also need help how to wrap the legend text if it is too long after placing the legend-text below the legend. jsfiddle.net/bdhbL1xy/4

I don't have access to attach an image please refer to fiddle link. Legend text displays below the Legend.

Answer (score 0):

I have found another solution:

```
legend: {
    symbolWidth: 100,
    symbolHeight: 2,
    labelFormatter: function () {
    if (this.legendItem) {
        $(this.legendItem.element).attr('x', 0).attr('y', 24);
    }
    if (this.legendSymbol) {
        $(this.legendSymbol.element).attr('y', 8);
    }
    return this.name;
    }
}
```

[image]